# Ubuntu on Nexus 10 for Surface 3-like experience?

Tags: bluetooth, desktop-environments, nexus-10

I know there is a "Ubuntu on Nexus" option out there, but what I want to know is can I have a "Surface 3 Pro" experience, i.e., touch as well as (bluetooth) mouse and keyboard with "regular" Ubuntu (14.10 or 15.03) desktop on my Nexus 10 (32Gb)? I've got my everyday computer desktop just where I want it with 14.10. Now I'd like that functionality 100% duplicated on my Nexus 10. Mainly, I'm not a big fan of the whole "app" experience. I want a desktop-like GUI experience.

BTW, could you do a regular install of "desktop" Ubuntu (14.10 or the new 15.03) on a Surface 3 Pro -- or any other of the newer touch-capable tablet-like laptops -- and have full touch/mouse/keyboard capabilities?